# How to shift rows of arrays stored in a list

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to rearrange NumPy arrays stored as list. I want to replace the rows that their second column is the same as the previous row. I case of having similar second rows in each array, I want to replace the second one by increasing their indices using a defined number. This is my simplified list (I purposefully showed the third column by alternative positive and negative numbers, in reality they are all positive):

```py
old_points = [np.array([[2., 0., 9.8],
                        [2., 0., -4.1],
                        [2., 1., 9.9],
                        [2., 1., -4.],
                        [2., 2., 9.],
                        [2., 2., -4.],
                        [3., 0., -4.1], 
                        [3., 1., -4.],
                        [3., 2., -4.9]]),
              np.array([[1., 0., 20.], 
                        [1., 0., -3.],
                        [1., 1., 22.2],
                        [1., 1., -3.8]])]
```

For the first array of `old_points` I want to add `2` to the index of the similar row, then add `1` and finally add `0`. I mean second row of first array (`[2., 0., -4.1`]) will become fourth of new one, the fourth (`[2., 1., -4.]`) will become the fifth in new one (increase of the indices decrease linearly by `1`, because our arrays has lost its second row) and finally the third row which is similar to its upper row (`[2., 2., -4.]`) will remain there with `0` movement. For the second array I want to move the first similar row (`[1., 0., -3.]`) one step ahead (from `old_points[1][1]` to `new_points[1][2]`). The last similar row again will change with 0 movement (i.e. remains in the same position).

```py
new_points = [np.array([[2., 0., 9.8],
                        [2., 1., 9.9],
                        [2., 2., 9.],
                        [2., 0., -4.1],
                        [2., 1., -4.],
                        [2., 2., -4.],
                        [3., 0., -4.1], 
                        [3., 1., -4.],
                        [3., 2., -4.9]]),
              np.array([[1., 0., 20.], 
                        [1., 1., 22.2],
                        [1., 0., -3.],
                        [1., 1., -3.8]])]
```

In advance, I do appreciate any help and contribution.

Comment: Treat each of those arrays separately.  The fact that they are in a list doesn't help you explain or process them together.

Comment: Dear @hpaulj, the point is that in some cases I have tens of arrays stored as a list and in fact they are jagged lists and I cannot put all of them as a single np array. Thats why they I have a list of arrays.

Comment: In any case you have to process each separately.

Comment: Can I rpocess them using a for loop starting with `for i in old_points:`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function rearranges an array in the way you described through NumPy's [advanced indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html?highlight=advanced%20indexing#advanced-indexing):

```py
def rearrange(arr):
    n_rows = arr.shape[0]
    all_rows = np.arange(n_rows)
    n_rows_even = n_rows - n_rows%2
    (pairs,) = np.nonzero(arr[0:n_rows_even:2, 1] == arr[1:n_rows_even:2, 1])
    
    top = 2*pairs
    middle = 2*pairs + 1
    bottom = np.setdiff1d(all_rows, np.concatenate([top, middle]))

    return arr[np.concatenate([top, middle, bottom])]
```

#### Demo

```py
In [1056]: for x, y in zip(old_points, new_points):
      ...:     x_new = rearrange(x)
      ...:     print(np.array_equal(x_new, y))
True
True
```